# Factorize $x^4 + 4x^2 +1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{29}$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

How do I factorize $x^4 + 4x^2 +1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{29}$?

I checked that the discriminant $D = 16 -4 = 12$ is not a square ($12^{14} = -1 \mod 29$) so this polynomial has no roots. Therefore it's either irreducible or is a product of two polynomials of degree $2$.

In theory I can find all irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ but $29$ is too big to do it by hand so what do I do?

Comment: Write it as a product $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and compare the coefficients. There is a solution to the resulting equations: $a=20$, $b=-1$, $c=9$, $d=-1$.

Comment: `Factor[x^4 + 4*x^2 + 1, Modulus -> 29]` Mathematica code shows the result is $\left(x^2+9 x+28\right) \left(x^2+20 x+28\right)$

Comment: A tip for a quicker solution: The polynomial $f(x)=x^4+4x^2+1$ has only even degree terms, so $f(-x)=f(x)$. So if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ is a factorization, $f(x)=g(-x)h(-x)$ is another. But factorization into irreducibles is unique. So either $g(x)=g(-x)$ (a case your discriminant calculation ruled out, do you see why), or $h(x)=g(-x)$ (looking for quadratic factors $g,h$). So you only need to consider factorizations of the form (building on Dietrich's comment):
$$f(x)=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b).$$
Only two unknowns now.

Comment: (cont'd) Admittedly the symmetry between the factors also follows easily from just expanding their product. Not relevant this time, but the case $g(-x)=g(x)$ would make you look for a factorization like $f(x)=(x^2+a)(x^2+b)$. This trick has recurred many times on the site already, searching for them may not be straight forward, but hopefully not too taxing either.

Comment: In his answer (+1) Mike uses automagically the consequences of the even/odd symmetry in relating the coefficients of the linear terms of the two factors, but could have saved one step by using it for the constant terms also even though he arrived at that conclusions rather speedily :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All operations below in this post are done in the field $\mathbb{F}_{29}$.

Write $x^4+4x^2+1 = (x^2+bx+c)(x^2-bx+d)$. [why can $x^4+4x^2+1$ be written this way]. Then doing out the multiplication yields

$$c-b^2+d=4$$
$$bc-bd = 0$$
$$cd = 1.$$

Now the equations $cd = 1$ and $c-b^2+d = 4$ together yields $b \not = 0$ [why is that] and thus the equation $c = d$. Thus plugging these into the above yields:

$$2c-b^2 = 4$$
$$c = d$$
$$c^2 = 1.$$

Now, one can check that $-2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_{29}$ so the equation $2c-b^2 = 4$ has no integral solution where $c = 1$. However, for $c = d = -1$ the equation $-b^2 = 6$ has the solution $b = 9$. So to conclude, plugging in $b=9$ and $c=d=-1$:

$$x^4+4x^2+1 = (x^2+bx+c)(x^2-bx+d) = (x^2+9x-1)(x^2-9x-1).$$